# MySQL Query to count how many databases a user owns?

Tags: mysql

Is there a query like

pseudo-code:

`SELECT databases FROM mysql.databases WHERE owner = 'myUser'`

or any query that'd do the job?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA;
```

(run as the user in Question)

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_SCHEMA FROM information_schema.SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES WHERE GRANTEE LIKE("'USERNAME'%") GROUP BY TABLE_SCHEMA
) AS baseview;
```

(Run as root)

Caveat: There is no such thing as an "Owner" for a database in MySQL, the above queries will show information about the databases a user has soem sort of access to.

Comment: this looks like closest we can get ... hmpf

Comment: It's as close as you can get without the notion of an "owner". BTW: The second query is ofcourse written so verbously, as you might need the inner query as well ...

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I can tell, there is no concept in MySQL of "Owner" of database or its objects, as there is in MS Access and MS SQL Server. I surmise this from the lack of "owner" field anywhere in mysql system tables. (http://www.wideman-one.com/gw/tech/mysql/perms/index.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You can count how many databases are associated with a user in the mysql database and the db table. This is the closest I can think of to "ownership" of a database by a user.

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT Db) FROM db WHERE User = 'someuser';
```

Answer (score 0):

**By using:**

```
SHOW DATABASES
```

You can only see the databases for which you have some kind of privilege, unless you have the global [SHOW DATABASES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-databases.html) privilege.

Read the [SHOW DATABASES Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-databases.html) for a better understanding of what you can achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You run the sql and then you see owner user of table.

The sql is `select * from information_schema. SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES where TABLE_SCHEMA='myUser'`

[Details about information_schema.SCHEMATA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-privileges-table.html)

Answer (score 0):

For just showing all the databases use

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA;
```